# How to trigger a method on React Native Animate.event while animation is happening?

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

React native has a useful way to create animations while you drag components via:

```
onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
  null,                // raw event arg ignored
  {dx: this._pan.x, dy: this._pan.y},    // gestureState arg
]),
```

However, while the element is dragging, I want it to call a function as it drags.

What I'm trying to do is when you drag the item to the drop-zone, I want to change the drop-zone background color (thus I need a function call to check if it is the drop-zone).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you need to fetch current dragged item position while it is being moved. I see two options:

1. Assuming that variable `_pan` is an instance of `Animated.ValueXY` you can add listener:

```js
this._pan.addListener(v=> {
    console.log('listener', val) // listener Object {x: 0, y: -16.5} 
});
```

2. If you need more information about a gesture you can use second argument of `Animated.event`

```js
let onMove = (e, gestureState) => {
        let {x0, y0, dx, dy, vx, vy} = gestureState;
        console.log(`x0:${x0}, y0:${y0}, dx:${dx}, dy:${dy}`); //x0:185.5, y0:309.5, dx:-1, dy:-12.5
        if (someFunctionThatComparesCoordinates(gestureState, dropzoneCoordinates)) {
            this.setState({
                dropzoneColor:'tomato'
            });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                dropzoneColor:'grey'
            });
        }
    };

PanResponder.create({
   onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([
      null,                // raw event arg ignored
      {dx: this._pan.x, dy: this._pan.y},    // gestureState arg
    ],{
        listener:onMove
    }),
});
```

Once you have necessary information you can change the state in the listener.